# Binding current Item for Carousel of Content Views (held in Observable Collection)

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, binding, carousel, observablecollection

I'm new to this community / Xamarin, and I've been stuck on this for a while so I need to reach out for help now.

I have a `CarouselView` of `ContentView`s and one of the view pages need to be validated so when the field is empty, I can revert back the correct carousel page using the Current Item binding BUT - although I am correctly retrieving the current item and the content view, the UI/binding isn't updating.

`ContentViews` is the `ObservableCollection`.

```
<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference carouselView}, Path=CurrentItem, 
       StringFormat='Current item: {0}', FallbackValue='Current item:'}"/>
    
<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference carouselView}, Path=Position, 
       StringFormat='Position: {0}'}"/>

<CarouselView
        x:Name="carouselView"
        IndicatorView="indicatorView"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ContentViews}"
        CurrentItem="{Binding CurrentItem}"
        Position="{Binding Position}"
        CurrentItemChanged="OnCurrentItemChanged"
        PositionChanged="OnPositionChanged">        
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentView Content="{Binding .}" />                    
           </DataTemplate>
        </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented in you Binding Source?

check this , also check that the `CarouselView` Binding source is your desired class.

Comment: I have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented on the model class where my ObservableCollection is created so when the CurrentItem and CurrentPosition is updated, it calls OnProperty changed but the carousel view still doesnt update with the new current item / position: modelclass.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentPosition");
modelclass.OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem"); Could you please advise on this?

Comment: what is the binding context of the carousel view?

Comment: I hope I've understood you correctly, let me know if not - Im  binding to CarouselViews which is an observablecollection holding a list of content views:                           
 public ObservableCollection<ContentView> ContentViews {
            get;       
            set;       
        } source = new List<ContentView>();
            source.Add(new MyView2());
            source.Add(new MyView3());                                                       
   ContentViews = new ObservableCollection<ContentView>(source.Skip(Position));

Comment: If I can reference the carousel view from another class, I could use ScrollTo instead but Im receiving the error, "carouselView is inaccessible due to its protection level" : carouselView.ScrollTo(3, position: (ScrollToPosition)enumPicker.SelectedItem, animate: animateSwitch.IsToggled); This would be an alternative method but anything that could work! I'm using the carouselViewsDemo to test this with ContentViews

Comment: please update the question with the view code behind as error shown means u might have the  private instead of public

Comment: I would be good to know if there are solutions to both methods so I've posted another question with this alternative method, I think this one would be easier to solve! - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64024185/call-scrollto-carousel-method-from-contentview-within-carouselview